# Testing for membership in a distribution with one single value

Tags: distributions, anderson-darling-test

I came across an interesting little quirk when I was coding up a hypothesis test in Python.

I was wondering why very time I tested some values for normalcy using the Anderson–Darling test, I was getting a positive.

Turns out my loop was just testing over one single value (oops)!  But then I got to thinking, I wonder if this is generally the case -- can a single real-valued number be shown to belong to every distribution that has real-valued numbers as it's support?  Is there a trivial result that states this somewhere in the statistical literature?

Comment: What do you mean by "getting a positive"? If you simply mean "failed to reject the null hypothesis", then you're gravely mistaken about what it implies. It certainly *doesn't* mean that the sample is "shown to belong" to the distribution being tested.

Comment: Are you estimating parameters, or is this  for fully specified distributions?

Comment: No, a single real-valued number cannot "belong to every distribution that has real-valued numbers as it's support".
For example, the continous [uniform distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29) on $[0,1]$ has real valued numbers as its support, though not all real valued numbers, but $x = 2$ cannot be a realization of this uniform distribution.
For a number to be a (potential) realisation from a distribution it needs to belong to its support.

Answer (score 1):

I see three* main possibilities:

1) You're dealing with fully specified distributions.

In this case, your assertion is plainly false, since a value like 3 is immediately rejected at typical significance levels

```
> ADGofTest::ad.test(3,pnorm)

    Anderson-Darling GoF Test

data:  3  and  pnorm
AD = 5.6091, p-value = 0.002753
alternative hypothesis: NA
```

2) you're fitting a mean, but specifying a standard deviation

In this case, the estimated mean is the single observation; it's impossible for an observation in the center of the estimated distribution to be "in the tail" of the distribution. The p-value will always be 1.

3) You're estimating both parameters. In that case you have some 'splainin' to do, because you can't estimate two parameters from one data point.

* (I discount the possibility that you're specifying a mean and estimating the variance. You'd have mentioned that specifically.)